# There was an error accessing `/home/userlinux/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47/versions`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

Tengo un problema al crear nuevas aplicaciones en *Ruby on Rails*; ejecuto el comando `rails new "myapp"` y me da este error:

> There was an error accessing `/home/userlinux/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47/versions`.
>
> The underlying system error is Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted @ utime_internal -
>   /home/userlinux/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47/versions

Al cambiarle los permisos al archivo *versions* se soluciona parcialmente para la aplicación específica sobre la que trabaja. Sin embargo me quisiera arreglar el problema de raíz.

Rails 5.1.4
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64-bit